# How to see all questions from a user

Tags: support, search

How can I see all questions from this user: https://stackoverflow.com/users/560942/jn-pdx

Answer (score 9):

- Searching for `user:560942 is:question` gives you the questions, OR,
- you can click his username in the given post and click the [`Questions` tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560942/jn-pdx?tab=questions)